# How do I create a spatial index in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, azure-maps

I have the class:

```
public class Address
{
    // street, city, etc.

    /// <summary>
    /// use X for longitude and Y for latitude.
    /// </summary>
    public NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point? Location { get; set; }
}
```

How in Entity Framework do I tell it to [create a spatial index](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-spatial-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for Address.Point?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-types/spatial check if it helps you?

Comment: @PratikLad Did I miss something? I saw nothing in there about how to code first create a spatial index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't create a spatial index in entity framework, you would create that in your spatial database. Entity framework builds queries that then call the database, the database processes the query and thus would need the spatial index. So you would have to go into your database manager and add the spatial index there. Once added, spatial queries should automatically make use of it.

Comment: I was hoping this could be set in `IEntityTypeConfiguration`. Oh well. For a column that's a Point, is `CREATE SPATIAL INDEX SIndx_SpatialTable_Address_Location ON Address(Location)` what I need? TIA

Comment: And do I set this in addition to making `Location` a standard index, or in addition to? I assume instead of. TIA.

Comment: Yes, that SQL statement is enough to setup a simple spatial index, and would be a lot better than no index. In the future, if you want to squeeze out a bit more query performance, you can look into tweaking some of the parameters such as adding a bounding box to limit narrow the area of coverage, grid resolution and cells per object, but no need to rush to that yet.

Comment: Other than the spatial index, I would add a primary index on an ID column. You only need a spatial index on the geography column and not any other index on that column